# How can I add GlassFish 4.1 server in Eclipse Neon 2?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, glassfish-4

I have a fresh installation of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers - for WIndows 64bit - Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) 

I have downloaded the newest editions of GlassFish server 4.1.1 - both Full & Web Profie
I've installed the latest GlassFish tolls using Eclipse Marketplace:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools

---

Now I am trying to add GlassFish Server to Eclipse using the latest JDK 8, but it complains that Java 6 or 7 is required:

[image]

---

OK, then I am trying to use the latest JDK 7 instead of 8, but this time it complains that this is an invalid GlassFish instalation.

[image]

---

How can I add GlassFish server to Eclipse, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 11):

After lots of trials and errors I finally managed  this issue. 
A `glassfish` subdirectory must be pointed instead of base installation directory, and everything works fine.

[image]

Comment: +1, Adding the subdirectory solved it. The error msg is strange as it misleads developer to think it as a JDK issue.

Comment: If you are getting an issue with "Java 6 or 7 is required", you just need to refresh the page so the error is reset.  You can do this by simply editing the location (like deleting and pasting the location again).

Comment: If you are getting an issue with "Java 6 or 7 is required" add an extra bacsklash to the jdk folder and this resolved the issue for me as Joost mentioned below.

Answer (score 3):

As for the "Java 6 or 7 is required"-problem; I managed to get past this by adding a trailing slash to the java location.

```sh
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle  # "Java 6 or 7 is required"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ # Works
```

This is on linux, so it might not apply to your windows environment.